# машинный код для DOS системы

Tags: ассемблер, dos

У меня есть машинный код, меня интересует, как его запустить и проверить, код системы dos, в каком расширении он должен быть?

```
b8  21 0a 00 00
a3  0c 10 00 06
b8  6f 72 6c 64
a3  08 10 00 06
b8  6f 2c 20 57
a3  04 10 00 06
b8  48 65 6c 6c
a3  00 10 00 06
b9  00 10 00 06
ba  10 00 00 00
bb  01 00 00 00
b8  04 00 00 00
cd 80
b8  01 00 00 00 
cd 80
b8 417574686f723a2049504f6c656b73656e6b6f
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, перевел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примеры исходников и их опкодов для "Hello World!" DOS и Win. Скачайте [отсюда](https://flatassembler.net/download.php) FASM, и скопируйте эти исходники в его окно. Теперь нажмите F9, и на выходе получите исполняемые файлы *.com и *.exe.

Вот код для MS-DOS:

```
;//---------------
org   100h
jmp   start

msg     db    'Hello World! $'

start:  mov   ah,9     ;// функция AH=9 сервиса DOS int-21h (вывод строки на консоль)
        mov   dx,msg   ;// адрес строки
        int   21h      ;// зовём сервис!
        xor   ax,ax    ;// fn.AH=0 сервиса биос (ждать нажатия клавиши)
        int   16h      ;// сервис BIOS для работы с клавиатурой
        ret            ;// выход из программы.
```

Опкоды программы выше (скопировать в блокнот и сохранить как *.com):
`EB0E48656C6C6F20576F726C64212024B409BA0201CD2131C0CD16C3`

Это то-же "Hello World", только для Windows от 2К до Win10. Опкоды размером 2 КБ, поэтому не привожу.

```
;// for Windows
;//---------------
format  pe gui
include 'win32ax.inc'
.data
msg     db  'Hello World!',0
.code
start:  invoke  MessageBox,0,msg,0,0 
        invoke  ExitProcess,0
.end start
```

Comment: СПАСИБО, ОЧЕНЬ ПОМОГЛИ

Comment: То есть, ассемблер компелирует на прямую в машинный код? Как я могу вам повысить рейтинг за помощ?)

Comment: Не только асм, но и любой компилятор сразу выдаёт машинный код. Просто у ассемблера он компактнее, без лишнего "мусора" (особенно для приложений Win). А рейтинг меня не интересует.

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3):

> в каком расширении он должен быть?

Скопируйте эти значения в любой НЕХ-редактор (HxD), и сохраните с расширением "BIN". Теперь открываете этот бинарник в дизассемблере, и таким образом получаете исходник. В данном случае он представляет собой "Hello World" для линуха, т.к. в коде имеются вызовы INT-80h. В конце есть строка автора - вот результат:

```
File: asm.bin
Size: 89
Type: Binary

* Entry Point:

00000000: B8210A0000           mov eax, 00000A21
00000005: A30C100006           mov [0600100C], eax
0000000A: B86F726C64           mov eax, 646C726F
0000000F: A308100006           mov [06001008], eax
00000014: B86F2C2057           mov eax, 57202C6F
00000019: A304100006           mov [06001004], eax
0000001E: B848656C6C           mov eax, 6C6C6548
00000023: A300100006           mov [06001000], eax

00000028: B900100006           mov ecx, 06001000
0000002D: BA10000000           mov edx, 00000010
00000032: BB01000000           mov ebx, 00000001
00000037: B804000000           mov eax, 00000004
0000003C: CD80                 int 80

0000003E: B801000000           mov eax, 00000001
00000043: CD80                 int 80

00000045: B841757468           Author: IPOleksenko
```

Comment: Грандиозно! В этом мире ещё не всё потеряно, пока деды знающие mасм живы!

Comment: @PRODIGY, а формат файла .com не подойдет? Могли бы вы мне дать сам файл со значениями что бы ясмог разобратся как оно работает? Спасибо

Comment: >>> `Могли бы вы мне дать сам файл со значениями` - ну так скопируйте строки из своего примера в блокнот, и убрав все пробелы, сохраните как "BIN" - вот вам и будет файл. А сохранять его как "СОМ" нельзя, т.к. это фрагмент кода, в котором должна быть секция-данных, куда вначале сохраняются значения из регистра `EAX`. Хотя попробуйте, может и получится. У меня нет линуха, а только Win, поэтому проверить не могу.

Comment: @PRODIGY, а не подскажете как сделать єто же, только в двоичном коде виндовс 10, я знаю что они отличаются в разніх системах. Как мне его запускать?

Comment: @IPOleksenko, в составе 64-бит систем (к которым относится и Win10) нет виртуальной машины MS-DOS `NTWDM`, поэтому этот файл вы не сможете на ней запустить. Однако можно установить на Win10 внешний эмулятор дос, типа BOCHS, DOSBox или другие.

Comment: @PRODIGY, а вы мне код в какой системе кинули, 16ричная? Могу ли я сделать запуск через Oracle VM VirtualBox?

Comment: @PRODIGY, Я запустил ваш код на линуксе, оно открылось текстом

Comment: "Hello World" чтоли? Так и должно быть.

Comment: @PRODIGY, Я имел в виду, оно открыло в блокноте код, а мне нужен Hello, world! в консоли, могли бы вы мне скинуть файл для любой ОС или сказать что мне делать что бы запустить у себя?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131585/discussion-between-ipoleksenko-and-prodigy).

Comment: @PRODIGY, код должен выглядеть так? ```b8210a0000a30c100006b86f726c64a308100006b86f2c2057a304100006b848656c6ca300100006b900100006ba10000000bb01000000b804000000cd80b801000000cd80b8417574686f723a2049504f6c656b73656e6b6f```